# Excel: Sorting cells with numbers

Tags: excel, vba

Current code:

```
        Public Sub A()
    j = 1
    For i = 1 To 10
        If Cells(i, 1) > 0 Then
         Cells(j, 2) = Cells(i, 1)
         j = j + 1
    [B1:B10].Sort key1:=[B1]
        End If

Next

End Sub
```

It sort of works in that it does copy from column A to B and sorts the positive numbers. My question now is how do I make it include negative numbers under the positive ones and write them down in a descending order? All in B column.

> Original: I'm currently learning VBA with excel and I'm stuck on one
>   task. I have a column A1:A20, each cell stores a number. I need to
>   copy over the same range to B1:B20 and arrange the numbers in
>   ascending order. My question is how would I do that?

Comment: Whilst there are several answers to your question, please note that going forward any questions should contain the code you tried, with an explanation of errors/issues which you are experiencing.

Answer (score 1):

```
[A1:A20].Copy [B1]
[B1:B20].Sort Key1:=[B1]
```

Comment: It doesn't get shorter than this. BTW e.g. [A1:A20] stands for ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("A1:A20"). Nice one.

Comment: @VBasic2008 Thanks! If to exclude named parameter `Key1`, it'd become a bit more shorter. :) Yes, this notation means range of active worksheet.

Comment: Can you imagine that my Array Bubble Sort Version below is actually three times faster at the given range? Of course it's only faster til about 120 records. After that it's exponentially downhill: at 1000 records it's at least 25 times slower, at 2000 records it's at least 75 times slower and at 10000 records it's at least 1200, yes 1200 times slower. Definitely gotta investigate Quicksort.

Comment: @JohnyL Thanks, I understand how the first line works but how does the second one determinate how the numbers should be sorted? For instance what If I wanted to sort them in a descending order or even list all >0 numbers in ascending order followed by <0 numbers all in the same B column?

Comment: @Rob If you want ascending or descending order, you can use `Order1` parameter: `Order1:=xlAscending` or `Order1:=xlDescending`. As for some other way of sorting, a specialized code must be written.

Comment: @JohnyL I see, is there some sort of a guide I could check out that explores various ways of sorting?

Answer (score 0):

Click on Developer and Record Macro (if you don't see the Developer menu [follow this tutorial](https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/questions/developer_tab2013.php).  Select cells A1:A20.  Copy to B1:B20 (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> works best).  Click on Data, Sort, don't expand selection, do not click on "My data has headers", click on OK.  Go back to the Developer menu and click on Stop Recording.  Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd> to examine the code you have just created.

Comment: Hi, thank you for replying. I followed the macro recording steps but once I press Alt-F11 it shows blank, doesn't display any code. Nvm, found it via Macro>selected the recorded one>edit and now it shows the code.

Answer (score 0):

## Paste a Sorted Range (Range, Array, Sort, Range)

```
Option Explicit

Sub PasteSortedRange()

  Const cStrSource As String = "A1:A20"   ' Source Range
  Const cStrTarget As String = "B1:B20"   ' Target Range

  Dim vntSource As Variant                ' Array

  Dim lngR1 As Long                       ' Outer Array Counter
  Dim lngR2 As Long                       ' Inner Array Counter
  Dim dblTemp As Double                   ' Temporary Number Storage

  With ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet

    ' Paste Source Range into Array.
    vntSource = .Range(cStrSource).Value2

    ' Sort Array.
    For lngR1 = 1 To UBound(vntSource) - 1
      For lngR2 = lngR1 + 1 To UBound(vntSource)
        If vntSource(lngR1, 1) > vntSource(lngR2, 1) Then
          dblTemp = vntSource(lngR1, 1)
          vntSource(lngR1, 1) = vntSource(lngR2, 1)
          vntSource(lngR2, 1) = dblTemp
        End If
      Next
    Next

    ' Paste Array into Target Range.
    .Range(cStrTarget) = vntSource

  End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have a column with number in range("A1:A20")

```
Sub paste_and_filter()

'Variable declaration
Dim rng As Range, rng2 As Range

'Set up of objects
Set rng = Range("A1:A20")
Set rng2 = Range("B1:B20")

'Copy and paste the column
rng.Select
Selection.Copy Destination:=rng2

'Filter
With ActiveSheet.Sort
    .SortFields.Clear
    .SortFields.Add rng2, xlSortOnValues, xlDescending, xlSortNormal
    .SetRange rng2
    .Header = False
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlSortColumns
    .Apply
End With

End Sub
```